# how to add ionic2 support to angular4 project?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I already have a project written in angular4, now, I have a desire to introduce ionic2 components into it so that it will be usable in mobile devices. I liked ionic2 as it has quite a lot mobile friendly features. 
I do not want to start new project all over again as our current ng4 app is very complicated, and I need to reuse as much as possible component/code. So ideally, if I just need to introduce some ionic2 module, then it will be terrific.

1. I introduced some ionic2 package into package.json

   ```
   "@ionic-native/core": "3.4.2",
   "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
   "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
   "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
   "ionic-angular": "3.0.1",
   "ionicons": "3.0.0",
   "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.0"
   ```
2. In app.module.ts. changed to this:

   ```
   import {NgModule, ErrorHandler} from '@angular/core'
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
   import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
   import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
   import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
   import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

   @NgModule( {
     imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot( AppComponent )],
     declarations: [AppComponent],
     bootstrap: [IonicApp],
     entryComponents: [
        AppComponent
     ],
     providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
         { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }
     ]
   })
   ```

When I start it, I did see quite a lot warning, such as:

```
WARNING in ./~/ionic-angular/umd/index.js
Critical dependencies:
6:24-31 require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./~/ionic-angular/umd/index.js 6:24-31

WARNING in ./~/ionic-angular/umd/config/config.js
Critical dependencies:
3:24-31 require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./~/ionic-angular/umd/config/config.js 3:24-31
```

also in browser, I did see:

```
./~/ionic-angular/umd/platform/platform-registry.js
Critical dependencies:
3:24-31 require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./~/ionic-angular/umd/platform/platform-registry.js 3:24-31
warnings @ client?cd17:68
client?cd17:68 ./~/ionic-angular/umd/config/mode-registry.js
Critical dependencies:
3:24-31 require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./~/ionic-angular/umd/config/mode-registry.js 3:24-31
```

Has anyone every successfully added ionic2 to ng2 project? How you do it?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you do it other way around? Create Ionic 3 project first and then add your Angular components to it?

Comment: Out app is already there, and it is based on webpack package, I don't see the solution to package project in ionic. I think the main purpose for ionic is to provide mobile app, not mobile web, right? So ideally, I should be able to use either ionic or nativescript to package our web app, and in the mean time, I can still deploy it as ng4 web directly